# Adding xercesImpl dependency then got error: the package javax.xml is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xsd, xml-validation

**the goal is to validate generated XML with **XSD 1.1****. Implemented code to validate:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

private boolean validateAgainstXSD(InputStream xml, InputStream xsd) {
    try {
        SchemaFactory factory = 
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
        return true;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

After implement the code, got **Error: Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often**, because the XSD to validate is 1.1 version, not 1.0. Then, found the open source dependency that supports XSD 1.1, Xerces. The dependency that implemented is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>id.fintax.espt</groupId>
    <artifactId>preparer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pajakio-backend-espt-preparer</name>
    <description>Backend service Preparer e-SPT Pajak.io</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.113.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But, got error on imported Class from the code above, sequentially:

```
- The package javax.xml is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)
- The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)
- The package javax.xml.validation is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xmlJava(8390063)
```

I'm so stuck and frustrated, because the validation using XSD 1.1 is a mandatory. Please help. Terima kasih.